# Delphi convert doc to pdf using Word ActiveX

Tags: delphi, ms-word, pdf-generation, activex

Did anyone already wrote code for converting doc or docx to pdf using Word 2007 or Word 2010 pdf export capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it with the following .vbs script. If you need it in Delphi code then it would be easy enough to convert:

```
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
Const wdRevisionsViewFinal = 0
Const wdFormatPDF = 17

Dim arguments
Set arguments = WScript.Arguments

Function DOC2PDF(sDocFile)

  Dim fso ' As FileSystemObject
  Dim wdo ' As Word.Application
  Dim wdoc ' As Word.Document
  Dim wdocs ' As Word.Documents

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sDocFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(sDocFile)
  sPdfFile = fso.GetParentFolderName(sDocFile) + "\" + fso.GetBaseName(sDocFile) + ".pdf"

  Set wdo = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set wdocs = wdo.Documents
  WScript.Echo "Opening: " + sDocFile
  Set wdoc = wdocs.Open(sDocFile)
  if fso.FileExists(sPdfFile) Then
    fso.DeleteFile sPdfFile, True
  End If
  WScript.Echo "Converting to PDF: " + sPdfFile
  Set wview = wdoc.ActiveWindow.View
  wview.ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
  wview.RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
  wdoc.SaveAs sPdfFile, wdFormatPDF
  WScript.Echo "Conversion completed"
  wdo.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges

  Set fso = Nothing
  Set wdo = Nothing

End Function

If arguments.Count=1 Then 
  Call DOC2PDF(arguments.Unnamed.Item(0))
Else
  WScript.Echo "Generates a PDF file from a Word document using Word PDF export."
  WScript.Echo ""
  WScript.Echo "Usage: doc2pdf.vbs <doc-file>"
  WScript.Echo ""
End If
```

Comment: I choose this as answer because it contains `wdDoNotSaveChanges` that helped me a lot! I lost 1 day and then I read again this question! Without using that word asks for saving and it is very annoying.

Answer (score 9):

I haven’t so far, but it shouldn’t be difficult:

- Create a Word COM server object using [`CreateOLEObject`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/OleAuto_CreateOleObject.html)`('Word.Application')`
- Open the document using [`Documents.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216319%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- Export the document to PDF using [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Here's a basic skeleton:

```
uses
  ComObj;
const
  wdExportFormatPDF = 17;
var 
  Word, Doc: OleVariant;
begin
  Word := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  Doc := Word.Documents.Open('C:\Document.docx');
  Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\Document.pdf', wdExportFormatPDF);
end;
```

Note that I’ve declare both the `Word` and `Doc` variables as OleVariants, so as to be version-indepent (i.e. this code will work whether you’re using Word 2007 or 2010).  You could also use the VCL Office component libraries if you wanted.  If you were to do a lot of processing in the document itself, that would definitely be faster.

Comment: Ok this works (I just replaced OleAuto with ComObj since I get that OleAuto is deprecated). Could you please tell me where to find the VCL Office component libraries: I remember having seen them in Delphi 7 Palette, but I don't see them in 2009.

Comment: @user193655: I seem to remember that it was a separate option in the installer, but I can’t be certain.  I haven’t got them in my D2010 setup either (but then I almost always use variants anyway, so as to be more flexible — I use VBA’s Object Browser to figure out the objects and methods to use)