# How to pass a parameter to a OLE Automation object such as MS Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole-automation

This is mainly a Delphi syntax related question. I need to set a parameter to True when calling a method of an OLE object.

I need to set in Word Automation (this is from [Word Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285885/en-us)):

```
wdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

As an example a dummy procedure where I would like to do this follows (please note WordApp.Quit!):

```
Procedure GetWordVersion;
    var
      WordApp: OLEVariant;
    begin
      { Create the OLE Object }
      Try
          WordApp := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
          WordVersion := WordApp.version;
           WordApp.Quit; // >-- HERE!!!!
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          WordVersion := -1;
        end;
      End;
end;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484721/delphi-convert-doc-to-pdf-using-word-activex) (check the accepted answer) the same thing seems to be done, but if I try it it:doesn't compile. I copy here only the relevant parts:

```
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
[...]

  wdo.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges 

[...]

End Function
```

Important:
instead of using

```
// this is from Word Reference    
wdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

it is possible to use

```
// from Word Reference
wdApp.NormalTemplate.Saved = True
```

Could anyone please modify my GetWordVersion procedure above so that either one of the 2 approaches above are used? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write:

Wordapp.Quit(SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges);

Or use this:

```
word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application'); 

.... 
word.DisplayAlerts := false;
word.Quit;
```

Comment: yes this works and it is also a quite compact solution, not too many lines to be added. Thanks

Comment: +1. @user193655, "not too many lines to be added"? Precisely 1; I don't think that's "too many". :-)